# Python: Get a 'caller' class instance in a 'calling' class and access 'caller's' instance variables

Tags: python

I need to get an instance of a 'caller' class in a 'calling' class. I can get the instance, I can call methods of the 'caller' class from the 'calling' class, but I can't access the instance variables. Does anyone know what is the problem here and how to solve it?

```
import inspect

class CallingClass():
    def __init__(self):
        prev_frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
        caller = prev_frame.f_locals['self'].__class__
        print(f"The caller is {caller.__name__}")
        caller.test_f(caller)

class CallerClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 100
        i = CallingClass()

    def test_f(self):
        print("This line is fine.")
        print(f"The value is {self.value} but it will fail.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = CallerClass()
```

The output is:

```
The caller is CallerClass
This line is fine.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\test.py", line 20, in <module>
    t = CallerClass()
  File "C:\test.py", line 13, in __init__
    i = CallingClass()
  File "C:\test.py", line 8, in __init__
    caller.test_f(caller)
  File "C:\test.py", line 17, in test_f
    print(f"The value is {self.value} but it will fail.")
AttributeError: type object 'CallerClass' has no attribute 'value'
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: "Calling" is just a synonym for "caller" in this context. Makes it confusing which one you meant to be what until looking at the code. The word you want instead of "calling" is "called" (sometimes you'll also see "callee" used - personally I prefer "called" because it's more in line with normal speech and "callee" is not really used in any other context).

Comment: This is probably a bad idea. But you are nearly there!  You just need to use the instance of `CallerClass` and call `test_f` on that,  instead of getting the class from the instance and calling the method on the class

Comment: A general tip: the exception error message gives a clue: `AttributeError: type object 'CallerClass' ...`: *type* object, not a normal object, a type object. This tells us that you're doing attribute access on the class definition itself, not on the instance (as if you did `CallerClass.value` instead of `CallerClass().value` or `self.value`). A normal attribute error on a class *instance* instead looks like this: `AttributeError: 'CallerClass' object ...`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't instantiated the instance. `prev_frame.f_locals['self'].__class__` refers to the actual class type (the definition). I don't believe you want to create a new instance, but if you did, it'd look like this:

```
caller = prev_frame.f_locals['self'].__class__()
```

However, from the code snippet I believe `prev_frame.f_locals['self']` would get you the instance instead.

Also worth pointing out, the only reason you make it to "This line is fine" is because you invoked it via `caller.test_f(caller)`. You passed the class definition to the method, taking up the required `self` parameter. If you had just called `caller.test_f()` (like you would if you actually had an instance) you wouldn't have made it as far because it would've complained about the missing required parameter `self`.

Comment: I +1'ed already, but I think from context the asker `caller = prev_frame.f_locals['self']`, not `caller = prev_frame.f_locals['self'].__class__()`, so I think that should be the main suggestion. (As written, the order and the formatting puts emphasis on the latter, making it look like the main suggestion at a glance.)

Comment: although this fixes the O.P. immediate problem advice should be given against using advanced introspection techniques for absolute "mundane" tasks such as this. What is being tried is obviously better achieved passing an explicit reference to the object of the CallerClass to the one associated with it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what you are trying to do, but I dop know youy are doing it the wrong way.

While what is causing the error in your code is somewhat easy to fix, and the part of retrieving the variables in the calling scope is working, **you should not do that in ordinary code**.

In one hand, it is true that Python allows one to do this, and all the methods you use are documented in the language spec, on the other hand, the ability to introspect caller functions scopes and variables, should be left to realize specialized code that will do something for which that is needed - like libs that will modify some runtime behavior of the program in one way or another, logging instrumentation, or other advanced stuff.

Your code is just plain calling code that need a reference to the caller class to change some attributes. The plain and simple way to do that is to pass the caller instance as an explicit parameter to the callee class - and that is it. Everything is handled with plain attributes, no introspection needed:

```
class CallingClass():
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        print(f"The caller class is {type(self.parent)}")
        self.parent.test_f()

class CallerClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 100
        i = CallingClass(self)

    def test_f(self):
        print("This line is fine.")
        print(f"The value is {self.value} but it will work.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = CallerClass()
```

Now, what is wrong with your code, is that among the frame instrospection and other checks that should be left for advanced and specialized code, you are mistaking a class for its instance: you are calling `.test_f` from the class, and passing the class itself as value, not the instance that is reflected in the `self` variable you read.

```
class CallingClass():
    def __init__(self):
        prev_frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
        caller_instance = prev_frame.f_locals['self']
        caller_class = caller_instance.__class__
        print(f"The caller is {caller_class.__name__}")
        caller_instance.test_f()
```

Besides that, one of the reasons I am so emphatic on the advising against introspection in this case is that corner cases could pop from lots of places: for example - the variable might not be called `self` in the calling scope or, you can't add a decorator to the method using introspection in this way, static analysis software such as mypy can't know what you are doing, etc...

Comment: Hi. Sure this example is not an actual project. In the actual project CallerClass represents a class with a strategy to make a data analysis. CallingClass represents a data. Each CallerClass instance may work with different instances of CallingClass, each instance of CallingClass may be used by more than 1 instance of CallerClass. Currently it is implemented as you propose but I do not like to pass an arg each time which I can get rid off.
Maybe redesign is a solution but I don't realize how it may be done if actually there are many Caller/Calling classes derived from an abstract parents.

Comment: Passing the parent arg is cleaner and will get you less problems in a complex project. Otherwise, implement the "calling" class as descriptors, by adding a '__get__'  method to them: they will get a clean reference to the owner instance whenever they are called, automatically, without the frame introspection mess.

listen up, for your own sake: it is 80kRep and 20+ years Python here, including authoring projects that _do use_ this kind of introspection,  telling you _not_ to go this way.